# jquery with sql server database html

Tags: jquery

i want to submit my data by jquery with html form to sql server,my form has some check box,radio,dropdown list....so how can i select that data from these element and then how  send to database..i already created my database with these fields...anyone help me out from this

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery docs for $.ajax()?  You'll also need something on the server between jQuery and the database, like PHP, ASP, ColdFusion, etc.  You can't just hand the data to the database directly.

Comment: are you using asp.net mvc framework?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us what you use on the server-side so I will assume it is PHP.

If you have this form:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="mytext" value="foo" />
    <button onclick="send()" value="Send" />
</form>
```

You can send it to the server this way:

```
function send() {
    var mytext = $('#mytext').val();
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_form.php",
        data: {
            "mytext" : mytext
        },
        async: true,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(response) { 
            result = response;
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert("Oh no! An error occured!");
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Of course, for this to work you need a `process_form.php` which accepts a POST parameter called `mytext`. Something like:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['mytext'])) {
    echo "You sent this text: " . $_POST['mytext'];
}
?>
```

The php script can communicate with the database too. Numerous tutorials exist on that topic.